# Add new values to beginning of existing array

Tags: java, arrays

I want a method that adds values to the array, starting from the beginning of it (if array's empty) or adding to the end (if it has values).

```
public void add(Task task) {
    Task[] newTaskList = new Task[taskList.length + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < taskList.length; i++) {
        newTaskList[i] = taskList[i];
    }

    newTaskList[newTaskList.length - 1] = task;
    taskList = newTaskList;
}
```

I declare my array as:

```
Task[] taskList = new Task[5];
```

If I run the following:

```
List1.add(task1);
List1.add(task2);
```

I get the following output:

```
=> null
=> null 
=> null
=> null
=> null
Task "TaskOne"
Task "TaskTwo"
```

However, I would like the following output:

```
Task 1
Task 2
```

So, question is - how to make things work in a way I've described above.

**Note:** I can't use `java.lang.util.List` or `ArrayList`.

Comment: You are declaring an array of `Task[5]`, which means you have 5 null references to tasks on declaration. Your logic is copying all those references over to a new array of `Task[6]` because you are saying length+1, then adding to the end the new task.

Comment: I assume "I can't use List" is because this some kind of study project and you are not allowed to? (that is the only valid reason to re-implement something that already exists in standard libraries)

Comment: You're right, study project.

Comment: @Jonny Henly MAAAAN, I love you, seriously. Thank you so much, you're simply the best. I wish I could write it by myself, but I'll do my best to understand it from start to end and reproduce, cause thx to you I've something to work with. Really, thanks is not enough, I thought I would never understand how to solve it, but you're my savior! Wish you all best.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the first index is null, if so overwrite the first index, if not overwrite the next null index.

You should check if all indexes are non-null before increasing the size of the array. Your `List` class should have an `int` that keeps track of the number of non-null indexes in the underlying array - you could call this variable `size`.

Or you could just use an `ArrayList` since it already does what you're trying to do, only better. Why reinvent the wheel?

**Update:**

Here is some working code:

```
class List {
    static Object taskList[] = new Object[5];
    boolean extraSpace = false;

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        List list = new List();

        list.add(new Object());
        list.add(new Object());

        for(int i = 0; i < taskList.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(taskList[i]);
        }
    }

    // Constructor
    public List() {
        for(int i = 0; i < taskList.length; i++) {
            if(taskList[i] == null) {
                extraSpace = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void add(Object task) {
        // check for any null indexes, if found fill them
        if(extraSpace) {
            boolean added = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < taskList.length; i++) {
                if(taskList[i] == null) {
                    if(!added) {
                        taskList[i] = task;
                        added = true;
                    } else {
                        extraSpace = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                extraSpace = false;
            }
        } else {
           // if no null indexes then create new array with +1 length, then
           // copy old array to new adding new task in the process.
           Object[] newTaskList = new Object[taskList.length + 1];
           for(int i = 0; i < taskList.length; i++) {
               newTaskList[i] = taskList[i];
           }
           newTaskList[newTaskList.length - 1] = task;
           taskList = newTaskList;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
java.lang.Object@106d69c
java.lang.Object@52e922
null
null
null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Pass your array into the method as well.

```
public void add(Task task, Task[] taskList){
  for(int i = 0; i = taskList.length;i++){
      if(taskList[i] == null){
          taskList[i] = task;
           return;
      }
   }
   Task[] newTaskList = new Task[taskList.length+1];
   newTaskList[taskList.length] = task;
   taskList = newTaskList;
 }
```

Comment: I'm greatly thankful, unfortunately I'm not allowed to add new parameters to the add function.

Comment: Rats...  Go with @Orin2005's answer then, it looks solid!

Answer (score 0):

You need to only grow the array if it needs to. Check to see if any references are null already, if they are add it, otherwise grow it by one and then add it to the end.

```
public void add(Task task) {
    boolean added = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < taskList.length; i++)
    {
        if(taskList[i] == null) {
            taskList[i] = task;
            added = true;
        }
    }

    if(!added) {
       //still not added, no null references, add to end of a newly declared array.
       Task[] newTaskList = new Task[taskList.length + 1];
       newTaskList[newTaskList.length -1] = task;
       taskList = newTaskList;
    }
}
```

Comment: => null  
=> null  
=> null  
=> null  
=> null  
Task "TaskTwo"  That's what I get.